# What is difference between jquery parse and jquery load ? Isn't load and parse same thing?

Tags: jquery

Difference between parsing data and loading data?

Comment: What do you mean by "jquery parse"? Can you give code examples?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ & http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Can you read the documentation? Then tell us which passages you're having trouble understanding? There's no point in us copy/pasting them for you if we don't know which bits you didn't get.

Comment: In general, your questions are very brief and lacking in evidence of prior research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery parseJSON:
Takes a well-formed JSON string
Returns the resulting JavaScript object.

Jquery load:
Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

1.`parse` just return the object while `load` place it into the matched element.

2.`load` load any data from the server while `parse` takes a well-formed JSON String

3.`load` "returns" HTML , while `parse` an object

Directly from Xander's link.